# Как подключиться из websocket к базе данных?

Tags: php, websocket

у меня есть код для работы с websocket, я пытаюсь записать сообщение пользователя в базу данных, но, когда пытаюсь подключиться к базе данных ($this->connectDB = new DB();), выдает ошибку подключения к websocket, сам websocket я запускаю, как параллельные процесс:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

exec("php chat-server.php param=value > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &");

require_once 'app/Bootstrap.php';

?>
```

Код создания объекта подключение к БД:

```
<?php

namespace App\core;

use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;
use App\data\DB;

class Chat implements MessageComponentInterface
{
    protected $clients;
    public $connectDB;

  public function __construct() {

    $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
    $this->connectDB = new DB();

  }
```

код подключения к БД:

```
<?php

namespace App\data;

use RedBeanPHP\R;
use RedBeanPHP\RedException;

try{
    R::setup('sqlite:' . DATA . 'db.sqlite');
    if(!R::testConnection()) {
        throw new RedException('No connection');
    }
}

catch(RedException $e){
    exit(var_dump($e));
}


class DB {
```

Не знаю, насколько понятен мой вопрос, но что-то тяжело сообразить, как правильно его сформулировать...

Comment: Поучиться задавать вопросы конечно не помешает. Для начала надо описывать конкретную проблему, а не какие-то посторонние материи. И описывать подробно. Вопрос ведь явно не "как подключаться", а "почему у меня не работает". И как мы должны ответить на это вопрос, если нас не потрудились поставить в известность даже о том, какую именно ошибку выдает. И как эта ошибка связана с базой данных

Comment: Проблему удалось решить - поскольку в классе Chat используется класс DB, создавать отдельное подключение не нужно, достаточно вызывать методы класса DB. Замечание по указанию ошибки в вопросе - принял, все верно, как раз по ней и смог разобраться, что к БД не мог подключиться, потому что нужно было отдельно подключить файл config с правильными путями для переменной DATA